# How should I save gallery images for a profile into a database?

Tags: php, codeigniter, gallery

I'm currently working on a gallery that allows you to upload to a screen and I want to know how should I save the images into a database so each selection of images is specific to each user. I have already completed a profile image upload that saves the link of the file for each user in a database, and now since Im trying to save a selection of images for each user I'm not sure how you would store an array of images for one ID. How could this be done? Currently my gallery database has 2 fields, user and galleryimage, but Im thinking this should become galleryimages since this is holding a selection of image names. My profile image before just stored the filename location as a varchar. Please point out to me how I should save a collection of images in one field, or if its not possible.

Here is what I have so far:

Controller:

```
class Gallery extends CI_Controller {



  function __construct()
   {
    // Call the parent construct
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model("profiles");
    $this->load->model("gal_model");
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

   }


  function index()
  {

            //The commented out lines below signify what I have so far and when I uncomment them the image will no longer upload
            // At the moment the images just upload to the page
    //$this->load->library('upload');
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');




    //$file_data = $this->upload->data();

    //$image = 'gallery_path'.$file_data['file_name'];

    //$data['image'] = 'gallery_path'.$file_data['file_name'];

    if($this->input->post('upload'))
    {

        $this->gal_model->do_upload();

    }




    //$this->gal_model->putGalleryImage($username, $image);


    $viewData['username'] = $username;

    $data['images'] = $this->gal_model->get_images();

    $this->load->view('shared/header');
    $this->load->view('gallery/galtitle', $viewData);
    $this->load->view('shared/nav');
    $this->load->view('gallery/galview', $data);
    $this->load->view('shared/footer');

}

}
```

Model:

```
class Gal_model extends CI_Model
{
var $gallery_path;
var $gallery_path_url;

function Gal_model()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->gallery_path = 'web-project-jb/assets/gallery';
    $this->gallery_path_url = base_url().'web-project-jb/assets/gallery/';
}   


function exists($username)
{
    $this->db->select('*')->from("gallery")->where('user', $username);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {

        return true;
        /*
         echo "user $user exists!";
        $row = $query->row();
        echo " and his profileimage is $row->profileimage";
        */
    }

    else

    {

        return false;
        //echo "no such user as $user!";
    }

}


    //this function is aiming to put the galleryimages into the database
function putGalleryImage($username, $image)
{


    $record = array('user' => $username, 'galleryimage' => $image);
    //$this->session->set_userdata($image);
    if ($this->exists($username))
    {
        $this->db->where('user', $username)->update('gallery', $record);


    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->where('user', $username)->insert('gallery', $record);

    }

}

function do_upload ()
{
   $config = array(
  'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png',
  'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path,
  'max_size'   => 10000     
            );


    $this->load->library("upload", $config);
    $this->upload->do_upload();
    $image_data = $this->upload->data();

    $config = array(
        'source_image'  => $image_data["full_path"],
        'new_image'     => $this->gallery_path. '/thumbs',
        'maintain_ration'   => true,
        'width' => 150,
        'height' => 100     


            );

    $this->load->library("image_lib", $config);
   $this->image_lib->resize();
}


function get_images()
{
    $files = scandir($this->gallery_path);
    $files = array_diff($files, array('.', '..', 'thumbs'));

    $images = array();

    foreach ($files as $file){
        $images[] = array(
            'url'   => $this->gallery_path_url.$file,
            'thumb_url' => $this->gallery_path_url.'thumbs/'.$file


                );

    }

    return $images;
}


 }
```

My gallery view:

```
  <?php if ( is_array($images) && (count($images)>0) ):
   foreach($images as $image): ?>
   <div class="thumb">
       <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
          <img src ="<?php echo $image['thumb_url']; ?>"/>
       </a> 
       <br>
   </div>
<?php endforeach; else:  ?>
    <div id = "blank_gallery">Please upload an Image</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn an array of image paths to comma-separated string. Then you can save it to a database easily.

Comment: Also, when you read it from the database,  you can turn it into an array using PHP's explode() method.

Comment: Could u please give me an example of this amended to my file_data in my index please?

Comment: In the function putGalleryImage, prepend this line to your code:

Answer (score 0):

You could simply name each uplaod with a unique name such as current unix timestamp and add the users id to the front of the name. Now you can recall any pictures because you know part of the file name is the users id. You would not need to store the links in the database.

Comment: ok - would this mean I would need to amend my database and add an ID field to it?

Comment: Would it be a good idea to then try this - $image = $id .$file_data['file_name'];

Comment: you need a unique id field in your database as standard practice. Follow me on this. I have a site and when a new user registers, it auto creates three folders in my gallery. one folder is named "userid". inside of it there are two folders - "public" and "private". now when this user upload a pic he can choose public or private and I know where they go by simply seting the path to "userid/public/" and then renaming the upload with current timestamp to insure no pics have same name.

Comment: you should not use $file_data['file_name'], what if user has two pics with same name. always rename pics with unique name. current timestamp is good because you can also use that to order pics from new to old

Comment: ok so my understanding of this is to create a  new Id field in my gallery db and then what would I need to change in my putGalleryimages function - thanks for your help btw

Comment: basically you will not need that function anymore. As long as each user has a unique userid, you will not need to store the path in the database. By knowing the userid, which can be held in a cookie or session, you can call it at any time to create the image file path on the fly.

Comment: OK - so assume I have created a new id field - sure I need some kind of function to at least put the image into the database, yes? How would this look?